# Which WMS is easiest to work with when using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm using QGIS to style shapefiles.

Currently I'm running GeoServer but not all the QGIS styles are imported to GeoServer (although its really easy to maintain it because of the layer preview and the integrated tile cache)

What is your recommendation for free WMS that is easy to integrate with QGIS shapefiles (and caching tiles - working with different kinds of projection)?

Comment: recommend you edit out EASIEST and simply request "an alternative, open source solution to GeoServer"

Comment: If you want an opensource WMS that uses SLD as the internal way of styling layers then you can try deegree.  An alternate WMS is MapServer, but it doesn't use SLD internally to style layers ~ though it can use SLD as part of a GetMap request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best integration is available through QGIS Server. You can simply publish the desktop project files through the server.

Step by step installation instructions are available for [Windows 7](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/) and [Ubuntu](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/).

QGIS Server can also be combined with TileCache: http://linfiniti.com/2011/09/qgis-server-with-tilecache/

Answer (score 0):

QGIS Server is an alternative to GeoServer.  Each has advantages and disadvantages.

I suggest that you benchmark a GeoServer instance and a QGIS Server instance (on Amazon search for `ami-0dc97a72` [GeoServer] and `ami-93fb75ec` [QGIS]) and compare both by placing each on a different layer on an OpenLayers map and switching each on and off alternately.

```
 // GEOSERVER untiled
 var format = 'image/png';
 var untiledGeoServer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      ratio: 1,
      url: 'http://34.42.165.189:8080/geoserver/your_folder_name/wms',
      params: {'FORMAT': format,
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'workspace:layer',
      }
    })
  });
  // GEOSERVER tiled
  var tiledGeoServer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://34.42.165.189:8080/geoserver/your_folder_name/wms',
      params: {'FORMAT': format, 
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',
               tiled: true,
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'workspace:layer',
         tilesOrigin: [latitude] + "," + [longitude]
      }
    })
  });
  // QGIS untiled
  var untiledQgis = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      ratio: 1,
      url: 'http://12.172.35.145/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi',
      params: {'FORMAT': format,
               'VERSION': '1.3.0',  
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'qgis_layer_name',
    MAP: '/var/www/html/qgis/projects/your_project_name.qgs'
      }
    })
  });
```

You will notice different artifacts in each zoom level for each server.  They don't serve EXACTLY the same image.

This is the [official instruction set QGIS Server 12.1](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/install.html), which works.

NOTE: QGIS Server install has a remote desktop installed, use vinagre from command line:

```
sudo vinagre 12.172.35.145:5901
```

and enter `myPasswo` for the password (change it later).

`12.172.35.145` and `34.42.165.189` should be replaced by your servers' IP's.